# Find and append text in all records of a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called tabTranslations and I need to find all occurrences of a word and change it to something else(whilst preserving any other words in the record). Is this possible without changing every record manually? As this would take me forever.

For example let's say I wanted to find the word "value" in all the records and change it to "values", but there may be a record with the text "some text value" in which case I would want it to then read "some text values".

I only really know the very basics of SQL so I'm unsure if I can do this or how I would go about it.

Comment: update tabTranslations set columnName = REPLACE(columnName,'value','values')

Comment: @KiranHegde Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work.

```
update tabTranslations 
set columnName = REPLACE(columnName,'value','values')
```